# How to implement UIView that performs inverse of contentStretch?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, geometry

The UIView [contentStretch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) property defines an area inside of which content is stretched to fill the view.  That's great and all, but I find myself in need of the exact opposite: I want a view where I can define a rect that does not stretch but have the outer edges stretched until they fill the view.

```
  +-------------------------------------------+
  |                                           |
  |         +----------+                      |
  |         |          |                      |
  |         |          |                      |
  |         |  Content |      Stretch to fill |
  |         |          |                      |
  |         |          |                      |
  |         +----------+                      |
  |                                           |
  +-------------------------------------------+
```

So in the above view, the outer rect is my proposed view.  The inner rect is the non-stretchable content.  Ideally I would like to be able to position the center point of the non-stretchable content anywhere within the outer rect and still have the outer bits fill to the edge.

Example usage scenario: a black overlay with a transparent center "hole" that follows the mouse / touch for exploring a scene with a flashlight, etc.

One way I thought to do this is to draw the content UIView, then draw four other views, size appropriately, to cover the outer area, but I was hoping for a single-view solution for smoother animating.  I'm guessing I'll need to have a single UIView and use Core Animation to get down and mess with its Layers?

Comment: Wow, excellent question... My thought process would be to fake it.  Add a black overlay, but have a UIView follow touches that is really just projecting parts of say an imageView underneath the black overlay.

Comment: But how do you see through the black overlay to the parts underneath?  Assume the Content rect has transparent bits.

Comment: Here's a link to a magnifying glass view that accepts UIViews as the content to magnify.  I haven't studied the implementation, so I can't provide specifics, but it works as promised: https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my first attempt (in my other answer to this question), doing everything in `drawRect:`, was a little laggy on my iPad 2.  I decided to redo it by creating a separate `CALayer` for each slice and let Core Animation worry about scaling the slices.

In this version, the work is done in the `layoutSubviews` method of my custom `UIView` subclass.  The system calls `layoutSubviews` whenever the view's size changes (including when the view first appears).  We can also ask the system to call `layoutSubviews` using the `setNeedsLayout` message.  The system automatically coalesces layout requests like it coalesces draw requests.

I'll need three private instance variables:

```
@implementation OutstretchView {
    CALayer *_slices[3][3];
    BOOL _imageDidChange : 1;
    BOOL _hasSlices : 1;
}
```

My `layoutSubviews` method starts by handling the easy cases of no image or no `fixedRect`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (!self.image) {
        [self hideSlices];
        self.layer.contents = nil;
        return;
    }

    if (CGRectIsNull(self.fixedRect)) {
        [self hideSlices];
        self.layer.contents = (__bridge id)self.image.CGImage;
        return;
    }
```

Then it lazily creates the nine slice layers if I haven't created them yet:

```
    if (!_hasSlices)
        [self makeSlices];
```

It recomputes the images for the slice layers if the image has changed.  The `_imageDidChange` flag is set in `setImage:`.

```
    if (_imageDidChange) {
        [self setSliceImages];
        _imageDidChange = NO;
    }
```

Finally, it sets the frame of each of the nine slice layers.

```
    [self setSliceFrames];
}
```

Of course, all the real work happens in the helper methods, but they're pretty simple.  Hiding the slices (when there's no image or no `fixedRect`) is trivial:

```
- (void)hideSlices {
    if (!_hasSlices)
        return;
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            _slices[y][x].hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the slice layers is also trivial:

```
- (void)makeSlices {
    if (_hasSlices)
        return;
    CALayer *myLayer = self.layer;
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            _slices[y][x] = [CALayer layer];
            [myLayer addSublayer:_slices[y][x]];
        }
    }
    _hasSlices = YES;
}
```

To make the slice images and set the slice layer frames, I'll need the `rect` helper function from my other answer:

```
static CGRect rect(CGFloat *xs, CGFloat *ys) {
    return CGRectMake(xs[0], ys[0], xs[1] - xs[0], ys[1] - ys[0]);
}
```

Creating the slice images requires a little work, because I have to compute the coordinates of the boundaries between the slices.  I use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to create the slice images from the user-supplied image.

```
- (void)setSliceImages {
    UIImage *image = self.image;
    CGImageRef cgImage = image.CGImage;
    CGFloat scale = image.scale;
    CGRect fixedRect = self.fixedRect;
    fixedRect.origin.x *= scale;
    fixedRect.origin.y *= scale;
    fixedRect.size.width *= scale;
    fixedRect.size.height *= scale;
    CGFloat xs[4] = { 0, fixedRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxX(fixedRect), CGImageGetWidth(cgImage) };
    CGFloat ys[4] = { 0, fixedRect.origin.y, CGRectGetMaxY(fixedRect), CGImageGetHeight(cgImage) };

    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            CGImageRef imageSlice = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgImage, rect(xs + x, ys + y));
            _slices[y][x].contents = (__bridge id)imageSlice;
            CGImageRelease(imageSlice);
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the slice layer frames is similar, although I don't have to handle the image scale here.  (Maybe I should be using the `UIScreen` scale?  Hmm.  It's confusing.  I haven't tried it on a Retina device.)

```
- (void)setSliceFrames {
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    CGRect fixedRect = self.fixedRect;
    CGPoint fixedCenter = self.fixedCenter;
    fixedRect = CGRectOffset(fixedRect, fixedCenter.x - fixedRect.size.width / 2, fixedCenter.y - fixedRect.size.height / 2);
    CGFloat xs[4] = { bounds.origin.x, fixedRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxX(fixedRect), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) };
    CGFloat ys[4] = { bounds.origin.y, fixedRect.origin.y, CGRectGetMaxY(fixedRect), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) };

    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            _slices[y][x].frame = rect(xs + x, ys + y);
        }
    }
}
```

This version seems much smoother on my iPad 2.  It might work very well on older devices too.

This version of my test project is [on github too](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-OutstretchView).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you wouldn't need four other views, you'd need eight.  The inner “fixed” rectangle divides the view into nine slices:

```
+----+-----+---------+
|    |     |         |
+----+-----+---------|
|    |fixed|         |
|    |     |         |
+----+-----+---------+
|    |     |         |
|    |     |         |
|    |     |         |
+----+-----+---------+
```

Notice that each of the nine slices may require a different combination of horizontal and vertical scaling.  It ends up looking like this:

[image: outside stretching demo]

Anyway, I thought it wouldn't be too hard to do this just by creating a `UIView` subclass that overrides `drawRect:`.

I named my subclass `OutstretchView` and gave it three properties:

```
@interface OutstretchView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect fixedRect;  // in image coordinates
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint fixedCenter;  // in view coordinates

@end
```

The `fixedRect` property defines the part of the image that should never be stretched.  The `fixedCenter` property defines where in the view that part of the image should be drawn.

To actually draw the nine slices of the image, it is helpful to define a method that takes a `CGRect` in image coordinates and a `CGRect` in view coordinates, and draws the specified part of the image in the specified part of the view.  I use Quartz 2D's clip and CTM features to do the “heavy lifting”:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)imageRect ofImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)viewRect {
    CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(gc); {
        CGContextClipToRect(gc, viewRect);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(gc, viewRect.origin.x, viewRect.origin.y);
        CGContextScaleCTM(gc, viewRect.size.width / imageRect.size.width, viewRect.size.height / imageRect.size.height);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(gc, -imageRect.origin.x, -imageRect.origin.y);
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    } CGContextRestoreGState(gc);
}
```

I'll also use a little helper method that creates a `CGRect` from an array of two X coordinates and an array of two Y coordinates:

```
static CGRect rect(CGFloat *xs, CGFloat *ys) {
    return CGRectMake(xs[0], ys[0], xs[1] - xs[0], ys[1] - ys[0]);
}
```

With those helpers, I can implement `drawRect:`.  First I handle the easy cases where there is either no image to draw, or no defined `fixedRect`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)dirtyRect {
    UIImage *image = self.image;
    if (!image)
        return;

    CGRect imageBounds = (CGRect){ CGPointZero, image.size };
    CGRect viewBounds = self.bounds;

    CGRect imageFixedRect = self.fixedRect;
    if (CGRectIsNull(imageFixedRect)) {
        [image drawInRect:viewBounds];
        return;
    }
```

Then I compute the rectangle in view coordinates where the fixed part of the image will be drawn:

```
    CGPoint imageFixedCenter = self.fixedCenter;
    CGRect viewFixedRect = CGRectOffset(imageFixedRect, imageFixedCenter.x - imageFixedRect.size.width / 2, imageFixedCenter.y - imageFixedRect.size.height / 2);
```

Next I make an array of the four (yes, four) X coordinates that define the edges of the slices in view coordinate space, and a similar array for the Y coordinates, and two more arrays for the coordinates in image coordinate space:

```
    CGFloat viewSlicesX[4] = { viewBounds.origin.x, viewFixedRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxX(viewFixedRect), CGRectGetMaxX(viewBounds) };
    CGFloat viewSlicesY[4] = { viewBounds.origin.y, viewFixedRect.origin.y, CGRectGetMaxY(viewFixedRect), CGRectGetMaxY(viewBounds) };
    CGFloat imageSlicesX[4] = { imageBounds.origin.x, imageFixedRect.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxX(imageFixedRect), CGRectGetMaxX(imageBounds) };
    CGFloat imageSlicesY[4] = { imageBounds.origin.y, imageFixedRect.origin.y, CGRectGetMaxY(imageFixedRect), CGRectGetMaxY(imageBounds) };
```

And finally the easy part, drawing the slices:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
            [self drawRect:rect(imageSlicesX + x, imageSlicesY + y) ofImage:image inRect:rect(viewSlicesX + x, viewSlicesY + y)];
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little laggy on my iPad 2.

This version of my test project is [on github](https://github.com/mayoff/stackoverflow-OutstretchView/tree/641f227cc73d8a5382e9d9166c444c11ad39c672).