# Making a view "see through" another view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, swift

I have 3 views, one is a background image(UIImageView), another blank white(alpha = 1) view on top of it and a label on the blank view. What I want to do is make the label "see" through the blank view to the background image(make the text color clear, and the text will get the color of the background image). Is such thing possible? Many thanks :)

Comment: yes, the procedure called masking, you may find some nice example of how an image can me masked by a text. as far as I remember the _CoreGraphics_ documentation on Apple's site has already such demonstration of _CoreGraphics'_ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could get rid of the all white view completely and instead make the label be the size of the background view and set `label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]` and `label.textColor = [UIColor clearColor]`.

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494803/74815).